# Setting up alias into Anaconda prompt inside Windows Terminal

Tags: windows, anaconda, alias, windows-terminal

Running anaconda inside windows terminal always points me into `(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>` and then I have to navigate tru directories to my target dir.

How can I add aliases into anaconda prompt inside windows terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the little arrow in Win Terminal is a `Settings` button. There you can open `settings.json` - inside this file you probably run your anaconda with command like:

```
"commandline": "cmd.exe /K C:\\Users\\Home\\anaconda3\\Scripts\\activate.bat"
```

then if you open `activate.bat` file, you can add `DOSKEY`s.

Example:

```
@REM Copyright (C) 2012 Anaconda, Inc
@REM SPDX-License-Identifier: BSD-3-Clause
@REM Test first character and last character of %1 to see if first character is a "
@REM   but the last character isn't.
@REM This was a bug as described in https://github.com/ContinuumIO/menuinst/issues/60
@REM When Anaconda Prompt has the form
@REM   %windir%\system32\cmd.exe "/K" "C:\Users\builder\Miniconda3\Scripts\activate.bat" "C:\Users\builder\Miniconda3"
@REM Rather than the correct
@REM    %windir%\system32\cmd.exe /K ""C:\Users\builder\Miniconda3\Scripts\activate.bat" "C:\Users\builder\Miniconda3""
@REM this solution taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/31359867
@set "_args1=%1"
@set _args1_first=%_args1:~0,1%
@set _args1_last=%_args1:~-1%
@set _args1_first=%_args1_first:"=+%
@set _args1_last=%_args1_last:"=+%
@set _args1=

@REM Here you can add your aliases
doskey cdp=cd C:\Users\Home\Desktop\Porn
doskey cdg=cd C:\Users\Home\Documents\GitHub\
cls

@if "%_args1_first%"=="+" if NOT "%_args1_last%"=="+" (
    @CALL "%~dp0..\condabin\conda.bat" activate
    @GOTO :End
)

@REM This may work if there are spaces in anything in %*
@CALL "%~dp0..\condabin\conda.bat" activate %*

:End
@set _args1_first=
@set _args1_last=
```

`cls` is just the command for clearing after.